# Difference between Bound column field and template column field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know about bound column field and template column field in  asp.net gridview mainly the difference. Please help me .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Boundfield` is a column bound direct to the datasource (column in a DB).

A `<asp:TemplateField />` is a customized column which can contain either a DB column as such  or you may join together columns for display.

Use `boundfield` to simply display the db column, use `TemplateField` to do something more fancy such as concatenate 2 db columns as a single gridview column or add some extra text/description/para  to the grid that  may not come from the db.

Lets see one basic example of when and how to use TemplateFields.

I want to have 2 columns in my grid that represent 2 columns in the db.
`FirstName` and `LastName` so  the GridView markup will have::

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"  />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"  />
```

But if you want to concatenate them together you need to use Template Fields:: 
Here **`eval("FirstName")`** is called as the data binding expression.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FullName" >
      <ItemTemplate>
             eval("FirstName") + " " + eval("LastName")
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Usually and most of the time , we use a template column when we need more than out of the box functionality for the column.

Answer (score 5):

BoundColumns you can bind to directly. 
TemplateColumns can contain more complex controls and you have to bind by using a data binding expression.

Comment: Thanks. Please explain me about data binding expression. I have a task were  i need to use bound column field and template column field without for loop in .cs file. Is it possible

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you never have to loop and do something like create each row 'by hand' when using BoundColums or TemplateColumns. Regarding data binding expressions, as user FlopScientist's answer was accepted i assume this is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

**Bound Field**

- It is used to display your Data in `GridView`.

**Template Field**

- If you want to do some more Action in `GridView` like Editing,
  Display Images etc Then you have to use Template Filed.