# What is the difference between asp:BoundField DataField and asp:BoundColumn Datafield

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a question:
What is the difference between the `asp:BoundField` DataField and the `asp:BoundColumn` Datafield when binding data in a `Gridview`?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Does this answer your question [Difference between Bound column field and template column field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106109/difference-between-bound-column-field-and-template-column-field)? Also [BoundField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield?view=netframework-4.8) and [BoundColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn?view=netframework-4.8) is useful.